# Sorting problem with 'query_posts' function in wordpress. Sort by custom field not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working with wordpress where i have a event listing system. There is a custom field in my post called starting_time which is unix timestamp. Now i want to short all posts by starting_time by this query_post command:

```
query_posts(array(
               'post_type' => 'event',
               'meta_key' => 'end_time',
               'meta_compare' =>'>=',
               'meta_value'=>time(),
               'order_by' => 'start_date',

             'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

But it not working. Here is the site http://citystir.com/events/. I am echoing the start_time in unix before the time remaining so you can see the value. And also my pagination is not working. May be I did something wrong in the query_post command.

Comment: Are you trying to sort it so that it only shows everything greater than today's date? It seems to be working...if anything you might want to change the 'order' => 'ASC' to 'order' => 'DSC'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the order_by command :) it is not order_by but orderby.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have the correct meta_key name used in the query. You say that the custom field is called **starting_time** but you set `order_by` to **start_date** in your code.

The order seems ok at **ASC** as this will show next up event.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have fixed the issue. The problem was with the order_by command :) it is not order_by but orderby.